# How to split a number into two at the decimal point in C?

Tags: c, numbers, fractions, decimal-point

I'm trying to split a number in C into two at the decimal point. For example, let's say the number is `1.5`, then I want to split it into `1` and `0.5`. How can I do this?

Comment: `intpart=(int)(1.5); decipart =1.5-intpart;`

Comment: @user12986714 Using an `(int)` to get the whole number portion of `some_double` is undefined behavior when whole number portion of `some_double` is outside the `int` range.

Comment: @user12986714: That fails for `double` values in which the integer part is not representable in the `int` type.

Comment: What type is the 'number'?  Is it a double?  String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `modf()` from `math.h` library:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main () {

   double value, fractional, integer;

   value = 8.123456;
   fractional = modf(value, &integer);

   printf("Integral part = %lf\n", integer);
   printf("Fraction Part = %lf \n", fractional);

   return(0);
}
```

Sample from [tutorialspoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_modf.htm)

Comment: Why does the integer variable have to be a double?

Comment: @Serket: Typical `int` types use 32 bits and cannot represent the integer values of all `double` values, which typically go to about 1.8e308. E.g., if you pass 0x1p50 + .5 to `modf`, you will get 0x1p50 (2\*\*50) in the integer result and .5 in the fraction result. If the integer result were delivered in an `int`, it would overflow.

Comment: @Serket, the arguments of modf are double.

Comment: @EricPostpischil can't you just use a long or a long long?

Comment: @anastaciu so the function returns the double part of the number?

Comment: @Serket: The integer part of a typical `double` may be up to almost 2\*\*1024. Do you know any C implementations in which `long long` or `uintmax_t` is 1024 bits?

Comment: @Serket, yes it does. The fractional part that is.

Answer (score 2):

The C standard specifies a `modf` function, declared in `<math.h>`. This code puts the integer part of the `double` `x` in `IntegerPart` and the fraction part in `FractionPart`:

```
double IntegerPart;
double FractionPart = modf(x, &IntegerPart);
```

Each of `IntegerPart` and `FractionPart` will have the same sign as `x`.